# Disabling notifications for a given app from a command line

Tags: notifications, settings, preferences, defaults

I would like to disable system noficiations for a selected application, like the Calendar in the screenshot below:
[image]
How can I do that from the command line?

Comment: Can you expand on your question? What exactly do you mean by 'programatically'?

Comment: @BaconDuctTape I actually mean using the command line (something like `defaults write`). Sorry for the confusion, edited my question